# How do I make two buttons side by side and responsive?

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design

I have a small task where it requires the two buttons side by side when using a desktop, and then when on mobile they are stacked on top of each other but have not decreased in size.

I have managed to make them stack on top of each other but they are different sizes? Whenever I defined the % size of the buttons it makes them squish together and look hideous when in device view.

```css
.button {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;; 
    border: none;
    color: #737373;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #003366;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:0.875em;
       display: inline-block;}
.button2 {
background-color: #003366;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 2px solid #003366;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:0.875em;
  display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="booking">
         <h2><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"          
         style="color:#33cc33;""> </i> Congratulations your jet2 holiday 
         booking has been confirmed</h2>

         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         Consectetur inventore, dignissimos quasi fuga sunt, nihil nemo 
         labore? Molestiae, eum, eos! Illum non laborum asperiores, 
         mollitia minima quasi atque. Eligendi, atque.</p>


  <button class="button">Cancel</button>
  <button class="button2">Continue</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your HTML?

Comment: Hello Jasmine, can you provide your code in jsfiddle with the html part

Comment: I am not used to jsfiddle so I hope this is helpful! https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=MK4G42vSV0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap them in a div, give them `percentage width`, make div have

```
div{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Padding could possibly mess up the responsiveness,so be aware of that as well

Comment: Thanks! I did wrap them in a div called container in the end and used text-align: center. But in future I will use this! Yikes, I know. It appears okay in the views they have asked for, luckily!

Comment: @Jasmine google something like flex froggy, its some game where you learn flex in css, it is very useful and much better than using bootstrap grids imo

Answer (score 0):

```html
`<div style="text-align: center; width: auto;">
  <div style="margin:5px; display: inline-block;"><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" >Save</button>
    </div>
  <div style="margin:5px; display: inline-block;"><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Cancel" >Cancel</button></div>
</div>`
```