# Unable to align buttons with CSS flex or grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page where I have 2 lists of buttons, each one in a div, side by side. I tried a CSS `grid` and `flex`, as you can see below. However, nothing seems to work, as the first div went all the way to the left margin and the other one under it.

How do I add some space to the left margin for the first column and from the half of the page for the second one?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 16px;
  font color: black;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #CC0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child">

    <a href="createCl.php"> <button style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
            <strong>Aggiungi</strong></button></a>Aggiungi</span> <br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-child">

    <a href="map.php"> <button style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
            <strong>Mappa</strong></button></a>Mappa Clienti</span>
  </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Share also your html and make a snippet to demonstrate the behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make two buttons side by side and responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563138/how-do-i-make-two-buttons-side-by-side-and-responsive)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of using flex. So if you're not locked in on using grid, here's a solution:

https://codepen.io/oppo_oskar/pen/yLVJQeL

```css
.grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
   
.buttons {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="left buttons">
        <button>Left1</button>
        <button>Left2</button>
        <button>Left3</button>
        <button>Left4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right buttons">
        <button>Right1</button>
        <button>Right2</button>
        <button>Right3</button>
        <button>Right4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For quick reading on how flex works, you can check out this site:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I've tried this method but it doesn't change anything. I'm updating the code and uploading the css button too.

Comment: @gigiopasticcio I think you need to explain what behavior you want more clearly. If I take your example code and set grid-container to have flex and flex-direction to rows, I get the expected behavior.

https://codepen.io/oppo_oskar/pen/eYBzQxv

Is this not how you want it?

Answer (score 2):

All your buttons must be inside a container, for example: `<div class="grid-container">`.

In CSS, `grid-template-columns: ;` defines how many columns you will have in your `.grid-container`.

For every `1fr` that you type into `grid-template-columns: ;` a new column will be created.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
    <button>Button3</button>
    <button>Button4</button>
    <button>Button5</button>
    <button>Button6</button>
</div>
```

I hope it helped a bit, please let me know. ^^'

Comment: Okay now I have two columns of buttons; but, the left one is too near the margin and the right one is too near from the half. What should I add to edit their position?

Comment: You have to put the `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` into the `.grid-container` not in the `.button`. But maybe could you try to describe a bit more, what you want to achieve?

Comment: So I want a column of buttons in the center of the left half, and the other column in the center of the right one.

Comment: Press on "Run code snippet" of my answer above. Isn't that what you want? 2 columns, with buttons in the center?

Comment: Yes, but what I am getting is a list of buttons on the left margin of the page and the other list on the margin of the half of the page.

Comment: I got it. I had a .center{} class. I modified it with left:25% and now the left list of buttons is in the center of the left half.

Comment: Normally you can center elements with `text-align: center;` or `margin: auto;`. I hope everything is fine now. Otherwise please update your code above and post all of your HTML and CSS. ^^'